# React-native Invariant Violation:_default(...)

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Sou iniciante no react-native, e para primeiro projeto decidi refazer um antigo trabalho de aula. Porém está ocorrendo esse erro, estava fazendo apenas uma tela de loggin e tentando registra-lá no App.js

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código Login

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  TextInput, 
  View,
  
} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component{

    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder ="Usuário"
                    onChangeText ={ text => this.setState({ user: text})}/>

                <TextInput placeholder ="Senha"
                    onChangeText ={ text => this.setState({ password: text})}/>

                
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```

codigo App.js

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import Login from '../BancaDeAvaliacao/src/screens/Login';


export default () => {
  AppRegistry.registerComponent('BancaDeAvaliacao', () => Login);
}
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que está acontecendo ? se eu utilizar apenas export default  Login; no arquivo App.js, ele carrega a página de login.

versão do react-native: 0.60.4
versão do react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Olá !

Poderia tirar um print ou me informar a estrutura de pastas que esta utilizando, creio que seu problema seja relacionado a este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449248/failure-to-call-appregistry-registercomponent)

**Exatamente nesta resposta:**
O problema é que o nome do aplicativo registrado não correspondia à pasta raiz. Portanto, se sua pasta raiz estiver /ChatApp, registre seu aplicativo da seguinte maneira:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ChatApp', ()  => App);
```

Creio que a sua importação, talvez esteja incorreta :

```
import Login from '../BancaDeAvaliacao/src/screens/Login';
```